# Is HttpUtility.UrlDecode or HttpUtility.UrlEncode available in wp8.1?

Tags: http, windows-phone-8.1

I cannot find the  HttpUtility.UrlDecode or HttpUtility.UrlEncode while attempting to develop some app in wp8.1. I had the System.net namespace included. Is this removed from 8.1?( I tried the same in wp8, and it was there). ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality is available for Windows Phone Runtime apps in System.Net.WebUtility rather than in System.Net.HttpUtility

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.net.webutility.urldecode.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.net.webutility.urlencode.aspx